# Excel - Text validation against cell range

Tags: excel, validation, text

I am looking to use Excel's data validation feature with text.  I have a cell which will be compared against data found in a 4 cell data range (F22:F25).  I have tried creating my own formula to test inputs. For example, Let's say F22:F25 had the following fruits: Apples, Grapes, Oranges, Pears.  If cell B5 had either of these fruits then it a pop up window should appear indicating that the fruit is already within that range.

I have tried OR(B5<>F22, B5<>F23, B5<>F24, B5<>F25), the NOT function, and a couple of others.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You want a message box, without using VBA? Or do you just want *some* way of notifying the user that it's in the range?

Comment: The message box comes along with the data validation feature of excel 2011 (Mac) version.  I just need to figure out how to use excel's formula to check if a text value is within the range F22:F25.

Comment: Oh, duh, I forgot Validation has the message box.  Why not use `Countif`? `=Countif($F$22:$F$25,$B$5)` which will return a number. If that number is greater than 0, you have a match.

Comment: If the value is found I want the message box to display and leave the cell blank.  Otherwise I want the value placed in the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom Data Validation is working for me. I am using excel 2010 (Windows 7).

I have `F2 to F5 as Apples, Grapes, Oranges, Pears`. I added Data validation in B2 such that `=IF(COUNTIF($F$2:$F$5,$B$2)=0,TRUE,FALSE)` with Allow drop down as `Custom`.

If I enter value in B2 which is in the ranges from F2 to F5 then count if becomes 1 so data validation fails. If I enter rest of data then works fine. Please refer below images.

[DataValidation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeYQ0.jpg)

[ValidationOne](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZ8ut.jpg)

[ValidationTwo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgspI.jpg)

Comment: Thank you!  That was exactly what I was looking for.